# sql subquery join group by

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to get a list of our users from our database along with the number of people from the same cohort as them - which in this case is defined as being from the same medical school at the same time.

`medical_school_id` is stored in the `doctor_record` table 
`graduation_dt` is stored in the `doctor_record` table as well.

I have managed to write this query out using a subquery which does a select statement counting the number of others for each row but this takes forever. My logic is telling me that I ought to run a simple GROUP BY query once first and then somehow JOIN the medical_school_id on to that.

The group by query is as follows

```
select count(ca.id) , cdr.medical_school_id, cdr.graduation_dt
from account ca
LEFT JOIN doctor cd on ca.id = cd.account_id
LEFT JOIN doctor_record cdr on cd.gmc_number = cdr.gmc_number
GROUP BY cdr.medical_school_id, cdr.graduation_dt
```

The long select query is

```
select a.id, a.email , dr.medical_school_id,
                     (select count(ba.id) from account ba
                    LEFT JOIN doctor bd on ba.id = bd.account_id
                    LEFT JOIN doctor_record bdr on bd.gmc_number = bdr.gmc_number
                    WHERE bdr.medical_school_id = dr.medical_school_id AND bdr.graduation_dt = dr.graduation_dt) AS med_count,


from account a
LEFT JOIN doctor d on a.id = d.account_id
LEFT JOIN doctor_record dr on d.gmc_number = dr.gmc_number
```

If you could push me in the right direction that would be amazing

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want window functions:

```
select a.id, a.email, dr.medical_school_id, dr.graduation_dt,
       count(*) over (partition by dr.medical_school_id, dr.graduation_dt) as cohort_size
from account a left join
     doctor d
     on a.id = d.account_id left join
     doctor_record dr
     on d.gmc_number = dr.gmc_number;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your same code for group by:

```
SELECT * FROM (
(

SELECT   acc.[id]
       , acc.[email]
FROM  
   account acc
LEFT JOIN 
   doctor doc 
ON 
   acc.id = doc.account_id
LEFT JOIN 
   doctor_record doc_rec 
ON 
   doc.gmc_number = doc_rec.gmc_number

) label

LEFT JOIN 
(

SELECT  count(acco.id) 
      , doc_reco.medical_school_id
      , doc_reco.graduation_dt
FROM 
   account acco
LEFT JOIN 
   doctor doct 
ON 
   acco.id = doct.account_id
LEFT JOIN 
   doctor_record doc_reco 
ON 
   doct.gmc_number = doc_reco.gmc_number
GROUP BY 
   doc_reco.medical_school_id, 
   doc_reco.graduation_dt

) count

ON 
count.[medical_school_id]=label.[medical_school_id]
AND
count.[graduation_dt]=label.[graduation_date]

)
```

Answer (score 0):

how about something like this?

```
select a.doctor_id
, count(*) - 1 
from doctor_record a
left join doctor_record b on a.medical_school_id = b.medical_school_id
                         and a.graduation_dt = b.graduation_dt
group by a.doctor_id
```

1. Subtract 1 from the count so that you're not counting the doctor in the "other folks in same cohort" number
2. I'm defining "same cohort" as "same medical school & graduation date".
3. I'm unclear on what GMC number is and how it is related. Is it something to do with cohort?